# Update a variable from a different class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python program which has a variable `access_token` in class1. In the constructor it is set to `self.access_token = ""`.

I want to update it from class2 to the token value. I've tried `calss1.access_token = token_value` but it remains unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a full, runnable sample of code that demonstrates the issue? (Not your whole project, just enough to reproduce the issue)

Comment: The point of a constructor is that it's constructing _an instance_ of `class1` and that instance has its own attributes like `access_token`. At any give time, you could have 0 instances or 3000 of them, so you can't change the value "on the class", you have to change the value on a specific instance—just like you can't append something to the `list` type, you can only append to a specific list. Which usually means passing that instance in as an argument to the `class2` method, or maybe passing it into `class2`'s initializer and storing it for later, etc., just like you'd do with a list.

Comment: By using `self.access_token = ""` you are setting an instance variable. And `calss1.access_token = token_value` is setting a class variable. They are different. I am not sure which one you desire but you can't use two different variable types to set the same variable.

Comment: The difference between them is that class variables only have one copy that is shared by all the different objects of a class, whereas every object has its own personal copy of an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have hit the usual class vs instance problem.

Assuming `class1` and `class2` like this:

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.access_token = ""
    # other parts elided

class class2:
    def method(self, other):
        # calculate a token
        token_value =   # details elided
        other.access_token = token_value   # update class1
```

The usage is like this:

```
c1 = class1()   # c1 has empty access_token

c2 = class2()   # c2 knows how to create the access_token
c2.method(c1)   # c2 calculates and updates c1
```